# why repulsive term in lennard jones potential is not related with spin state?

Tags: solid-state-physics, pauli-exclusion-principle

I have read solid state physics which is wrote by kittle.
it said that repulsive term is relate with pauli exclusion principle and we can descride it r^-12.
but i don`t know why the two cases, for example two hydrogen atoms which have same electron spin or different spin, have the same dependence r^-12.
i think that if they are the same, then more repulsive force are acted than the difference one because of pauli explosion principle.

Comment: You should think of the Lennard-Jones as a very crude approximation. There should be more dependencies as you mention, but we are being lazy with how much computation we do.

Comment: Yes, I believe that it is $r^{-12}$ just because it happends to be square of asymptotic scaling of dipolar vdw-fluctuations $r^{-6}$. And square is faster to calculate than arbitary exponent. In paper it makes equilibrium distance solvable with quadratic equation and with computer FPUs it is faster as well.